# How to convert a static array to a dynamic one?

Tags: arrays, rust

```
struct Foo(i32);

fn print_foo(xs: &[Foo]){
    for i in xs{
        println!("{}", i.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let xs = [Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)];
    // need do something in this line to conert xs to &[Foo]
    print_foo(xs); // error: expected &[Foo] but found [Foo; 3]

}
```

The variable `xs` needs to be converted to `&[Foo]` but searching didn't give me the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a reference to it (`&xs`), you’ll have something of type `&[Foo; 3]`, which coerces freely to the dynamically sized slice `&[Foo]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_foo(&xs);
```

By the way, `&[Foo]` is not a dynamic array; it's a *slice*. A slice is a view into an array.

Comment: To say that a slice is a view into an array is a misrepresentation; it’s a view into *any* suitable chunk of memory. That could be an array (or a part thereof), a vector, a string (`&[u8]` only, no other type of slice), *&c.*

Comment: I consider vectors and strings to contain an array (even if it's not a fixed-size array), so from this point of view, the statement remains true.

Comment: “Array” is a very specific term in Rust: `[T; n]`. Nothing else.

Comment: Your point is good, but this belongs as a comment, not an answer.